# Undefined offset :1 even using empty()

Tags: php

So I put 2 values in my checkbox,the first one is the amount and the second one is the id.  I already use empty() but still I cant solve this "Undefined offset" problem. Any suggestion?

```
 <input type="checkbox"  name="checkbox[]" value="1::<?php echo $players->player_id?>">
 <input type="checkbox"  name="checkbox2[]" value=".5::<?php echo $players->player_id?>">
 <input type="checkbox"  name="checkbox3[]" value=".5::<?php echo $players->player_id?>">
 <input type="checkbox"  name="checkbox4[]" value="-.5::<?php echo $players->player_id?>">
```

And in my contoller

```
public function update() {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->input->post('checkbox')); $i++) {
        $checkboxvalue = explode('::', $this->input->post('checkbox')[$i]);
        $checkboxvalue2 = explode('::', $this->input->post('checkbox2')[$i]);
        $checkboxvalue3 = explode('::', $this->input->post('checkbox3')[$i]);
        $checkboxvalue4 = explode('::', $this->input->post('checkbox4')[$i]);
        if(empty($checkboxvalue[0])){
            $checkboxvalue[0] = 0;
        }
        if(empty($checkboxvalue[0])){
            $checkboxvalue2[0] = 0;
        }
        if(empty($checkboxvalue[0])){
            $checkboxvalue3[0] = 0;
        }
        if(empty($checkboxvalue[0])){
            $checkboxvalue4[0] = 0;
        }
        $totals = $checkboxvalue[0] + $checkboxvalue2[0] + $checkboxvalue3[0] + $checkboxvalue4[0];
        $data = array(
            'player_id' => $checkboxvalue[1],
            'player_att1' => $checkboxvalue[0],
            'player_att2' => $checkboxvalue2[0],
            'player_att3' => $checkboxvalue3[0],
            'player_att4' => $checkboxvalue4[0],
            'player_atotal' => $totals,
        );
        $this->load->model('Evaluation_model');
        $this->Evaluation_model->editview($checkboxvalue[1], $data);
        $checkboxvalue = array();
    }
    redirect(base_url('Evaluations'));
}
```

Help is very much appreciated.

PS:
[image]

Comment: You should use the same name for all check boxes so you can loop through them and get values.  What you have done is have different check boxes as arrays.. Long story short, make all the checkboxes name='checkbox[]'

Comment: @Akintunde I suspect this is one row of a multi-row form, and each row has 4 checkboxes. So the array goes across rows.

Comment: Oops!  Seems you are right @Barmar.  Also OP did not explain in details what the above code should do. This looks like code igniter syntax.  The line $this->input->post('checkbox')  seems like its looking for just the attribute checkbox and not checkbox2 for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only checked boxes get sent to the server. So each checkbox array will have different numbers of elements depending on how many of those boxes are checked. You can't use `count($this->input->post('checkbox'))` as the limit for all the checkboxes.

You need to use a separate loop for each checkbox. And you can use an associative array keyed off the player IDs to gather the data from each checkbox.

```
public function update() {
    $players = array();

    foreach ($this->input->post('checkbox') as $checkbox) {
        list($value, $player_id) = explode('::', $checkbox);
        self::update_player($players, $player_id, 'player_att1', $value);
    }
    foreach ($this->input->post('checkbox2') as $checkbox) {
        list($value, $player_id) = explode('::', $checkbox);
        self::update_player($players, $player_id, 'player_att2', $value);
    }
    foreach ($this->input->post('checkbox3') as $checkbox) {
        list($value, $player_id) = explode('::', $checkbox);
        self::update_player($players, $player_id, 'player_att3', $value);
    }
    foreach ($this->input->post('checkbox4') as $checkbox) {
        list($value, $player_id) = explode('::', $checkbox);
        self::update_player($players, $player_id, 'player_att4', $value);
    }
    $this->load->model('Evaluation_model');
    foreach ($players as $player_id => $data) {
        $this->Evaluation_model->editview($player_id, $data);
    }
    redirect(base_url('Evaluations'));
}

static function update_player(&$players, $id, $property, $value) {
    if (!isset($players[$id])) {
        $players[$id] = array(
            'player_id' => $id,
            'player_att1' => 0,
            'player_att2' => 0,
            'player_att3' => 0,
            'player_att4' => 0,
            'player_atotal' => 0
        );
    }
    $players[$id][$property] = $value;
    $players[$id]['player_atotal'] += $value;
}
```

Comment: But from this, how do you identify which checkbox set is associated with each row of the table? You can't. You need to name the checkboxes like `checkbox[0]` to get a consistent array.

Comment: I don't think the row is needed, the player ID is in the value.

Comment: Fair point, although that seems like an odd way to submit form data :D I guess ideally it would be along the lines of `name="players[#ID][#KEY]" value="#VALUE"`...

Comment: See [Passing by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) to understand the `&`.

Comment: @Barmar I really can't combine them, please do me a favor and show me the answer, I'll study it how.

Comment: What's missing from the answer? You need me to write the same thing with `'player_att3'` and `player_att4'?

Comment: Why do you have the loops inside the `update_player` function?

Comment: `update_player` is a utility function used inside the loops, to avoid repeating similar code for each checkbox.

Comment: I changed the way I call `$this->Evaluation_model->editview`, it was still using one of your variables.

Comment: Its still not right, it gives me 1 row with the total amount of the checked boxes and the player id wasn't register too

Comment: and player_id is always = 1, not the row of the player.

Comment: It gets player_id from `value="1::<?php echo $players->player_id?>`. I don't see how it can always be 1.

Comment: Check your HTML, make sure the player IDs are correct in the checkbox values.

Comment: I forgot to remove the isset() at my view, it worked perfeclty now! Thanks a bunch! :*